# How to iterate over a json array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the Gson library to create a json from java and it returns me something like that:

```
[{"title":"title1","author":"author1"},{"title":"title2","author":"author2"}]
```

How can I parse and access to the values in my js file?

Comment: what do you wan to acces?

Comment: For example the value of "title"

Comment: Did you save it to a file? Is that being generated by a server? Where does the data live? Are you familiar with AJAX? Are you familiar with `for` loops? What have you tried on your own?

Answer (score 1):

i use a lot w3schools site [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

```js
var text = '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.name + "<br>" +
obj.street + "<br>" +
obj.phone;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>JSON Object Creation in JavaScript</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting these is actually pretty easy in JS because JSON Objects are just considered Objects by js.

You can do this like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    let currObj = myArray[i];
    let keys = Object.keys(currObj);
    for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        let myValue = keys[j];
        doSomethingWithMyValue(myValue);
    }
}
```

That will get every value for every key in every object in your array. This should give you a pretty good baseline for how these objects work.

Edit: Worth noting, there is also a Object.values(obj), method, which will return a list of all the values in your object in order, but it currently has very poor browser support, so you are much safer using Object.keys and then iterating over the keys like I showed above.

Comment: Just a cautionary note: `let` is a keyword that is available only in the latest browsers. It is possible to get libraries to "transpile" or compile this in order to work on older browsers, but that is very advanced for newbies. `let` is a keyword from ECMA Script 2015 (or E5) and is only available on IE 11+, MS Edge 12+, etc.

Comment: Hmmm... That's an interesting opinion. I would argue that let is much safer to teach newbies because they are rarely using old libraries on ie6, and it keeps them from making namespace errors.

Comment: True. It is better to learn the latest, but it depends on whether or not your customers have the latest browsers. If you want to support the old, you have to learn the new AND a whole lot of work to support the old.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what you want to do with the data, and whether or not there are duplicate titles, as in your example. However...

```
 var a = [{"title":"title1","author":"author1"},{"title":"title2","author":"author2"}];
 a.forEach(function(v) {
   doSomething(v.title, v.author);
 });
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

With a `for` loop

#### If you get the JSON as an array

```js
var json = [{"title":"title1","author":"author1"},{"title":"title2","author":"author2"}];
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
 console.log(json[i].title, json[i].author);
}
```

#### If you get the JSON as a string

```js
var string = '[{"title":"title1","author":"author1"},{"title":"title2","author":"author2"}]';
var json = JSON.parse(string);

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
 console.log(json[i].title, json[i].author);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Here an example ---
var elements=[{id:123, name:'lorem'},{id:456, name:'ipsum'},{id:998, name:'verrugas'}];
for (item in elements){
   console.log(elements[item].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was a very noob question.

Firstly, to access to the values I have to do something like

*data.title*

In my case I had an array so I had to use something like

```
var j = JSON.parse(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length ; i++) {
         console.log(j[i].title);
      }
```

When I run for the first time this function it said "JSon unexpected identifier Object, that because Gson was returning already a json and javascript was trying to create a json of a json, so I removed the JSON.parse(data) and now it works!

Thanks u all